# "Header" information row required for logical SQL information chunk

Tags: sql

I have this current view (SQL Query already developed):

```
| Application Control ID  |  Application Name  |  System  |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| A0037                   |  ABR_APP1          |  ABR     |
| A1047                   |  ABR_APP2          |  ABR     |
| A2051                   |  ABR_APP3          |  ABR     |
| A2053                   |  ABR_APP4          |  ABR     |
| A1909                   |  ABR_APP5          |  ABR     |
| A0032                   |  AIS_APP1          |  AIS     |
| A0029                   |  AIS_APP2          |  AIS     |
| A0030                   |  AIS_APP3          |  AIS     |
| A0039                   |  AOL_APP1          |  AOL     |
| A0038                   |  AOL_APP2          |  AOL     |
```

I need to change it to this:

```
| Application Control ID | Application Name | System |
------------------------------------------------------
| S0001                  | [blank]          | ABR    |
| A0037                  | ABR_APP1         | ABR    |
| A1047                  | ABR_APP2         | ABR    |
| A2051                  | ABR_APP3         | ABR    |
| A2053                  | ABR_APP4         | ABR    |
| A1909                  | ABR_APP5         | ABR    |
| S0002                  | [blank]          | AIS    |
| A0032                  | AIS_APP1         | AIS    |
| A0029                  | AIS_APP2         | AIS    |
| A0030                  | AIS_APP3         | AIS    |
| S0003                  | [blank]          | AOL    |
| A0039                  | AOL_APP1         | AOL    |
| A0038                  | AOL_APP2         | AOL    |
```

The datamart tables in our knowledge management system are as follows:
    - ATO_ATO_Application
    - ATO_ATO_System
    - ATO_APPLICATION_TO_SYSTEM

Question: Those sub-headers (S0001..., S0002..., S0003...) – are they easy to add to the view through SQL query programming?
    - Somehow I need to show these “sub-header” data from the ATO_ATO_System table and place it above the logical application chunk / set as per shown above.

Thanks in advance..

Albert

Comment: I think we'll need some more information to help you here. Perhaps include the query you're currently using to return this data, as well as the table structure from which the sub-headers are coming. Additionally, which RDBMS are you using (Sql Server, Oracle, MySql, etc)?

Comment: Which database technology?